# ActiveRecord change or reset ordering defined in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a function which uses another functions output: an ActiveRecord::Relation object. This relation already has an order clause:

```
# This function cannot be changed
def black_box
  Product.where('...').order("name")
end

def my_func
  black_box.order("id")
end
```

when I execute the relation the ORDER_BY clause is ordered by the order functions:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE ...
ORDER_BY('name', 'id') // The first order function, then the second
```

Is there any way I can specify the relation to insert my order function BEFORE the previous one? So the SQL would look like so?

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE ...
ORDER_BY('id', 'name')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) method to reset the original order and add your new order by column.

**reorder(*args)**

Replaces any existing order defined on the relation with the specified order.

```
User.order('email DESC').reorder('id ASC') # generated SQL has 'ORDER BY id ASC'
```

Subsequent calls to order on the same relation will be appended. For example:

```
User.order('email DESC').reorder('id ASC').order('name ASC')
# generates a query with 'ORDER BY id ASC, name ASC'.
```